# Atomic increment via operate command using java client (5.1.5.1) fails

Tags: java, client, aerospike, compare-and-swap

I am trying to do atomic operations on a single bin set. However I am noticing a strange behaviour where randomly record is not getting incremented/decremented. Operate command is returning null in response. Not getting any exception as well. Sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't.

Attempted to check using both **persistent** and **inmemory** storage. It's a clustered environment of 3 nodes.

For some cases it gave Hot key error which i was able to resolve by setting the property **transaction-pending-limit** = 0.

**Aerospike client :**

```
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
                 <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
                 <version>5.1.5.1</version>
             </dependency>
```

**Operate command :**

```
    public long incrementAndGetBinValue(AerospikeClient aerospikeClient, String key, Bin bin, long value, Key asKey) {
        Record record;
        try {
            record = aerospikeClient.operate(aerospikeClient.writePolicyDefault, asKey, Operation.add(bin), Operation.get(bin.name));
            logger.info("Aeroospike record {} ", record);
        } catch (AerospikeException exception) {
            logger.error("Aerospike Exception while incrementing bin {} ,key {} by value {} error : {}", bin.name, key, value, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
            throw new NexusException(ErrorCodes.AEROSPIKE_OPERATION_ERROR, "aerospike exception operation error");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Exception while incrementing bin {} ,key {} by value {} error : {}", bin.name, key, value, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
        }
        if (record == null) {
            logger.error("incrementAndGetBinValue :  No record returned for key {} ,bin {}", key, bin.name);
            throw new NexusException(ErrorCodes.AEROSPIKE_NO_RECORD_FOUND, "aerospike no record returned");
        }
        return record.getLong(bin.name);
    }
```

**Policy :**

```
        ClientPolicy policy = new ClientPolicy();
        policy.timeout = 5000;
        WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
        writePolicy.socketTimeout = 60000;
        writePolicy.maxRetries = 2;
        writePolicy.sendKey = true;
        writePolicy.expiration = -1; // never expire record
        writePolicy.respondAllOps=true;
        writePolicy.durableDelete=true;
        policy.writePolicyDefault = writePolicy;

        Policy readPolicy = new Policy();
        readPolicy.maxRetries = 2;
        readPolicy.socketTimeout = 5000;
        policy.readPolicyDefault = readPolicy;
        return policy;
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - you are passing long value but not using it.
2 - it has to be used in the Bin constructor when passing to Operation.add().

For e.g.

```
Bin bin1 = new Bin("name", "John Doe");
Bin bin2 = new Bin("age", 32);
Bin bin3 = new Bin("greeting", "Hello World!");

// Write a record
client.put(null, key, bin1, bin2, bin3);
//This creates the record with bin2=32

import com.aerospike.client.Operation;
Bin addTobin2 = new Bin("age", 4);
client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(addTobin2));
```

Here I expect the put() call to create the bin with value 32.
Then, the operate() call with Operation.add(addTobin2)... will take that the value 4 and add to 32. Net value expected: 36.

```
// Read the record
Record record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);
Record values are:
(gen:6),(exp:394484896),(bins:(name:John Doe),(age:36),(greeting:Hello World!))
```

Upsert Code Demo:

```
client.delete(null,key);

// Write a record
import com.aerospike.client.Operation;

Bin bin2 = new Bin("test", 2);

client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(bin2));
Record record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);

client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(bin2));
Record record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);

client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(bin2));
Record record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);

(gen:1),(exp:394490665),(bins:(test:2))
(gen:2),(exp:394490665),(bins:(test:4))
(gen:3),(exp:394490666),(bins:(test:6))
```

Multiple Ops done Atomically / code example:

```
client.delete(null,key);

// Write a record
import com.aerospike.client.Operation;

Bin bin2 = new Bin("test", 2);
System.out.println(bin2);

Record record = client.operate(null,key, 
                               Operation.add(bin2),
                               Operation.get(bin2.name),
                               Operation.add(bin2),
                               Operation.get(bin2.name),
                               Operation.add(bin2),
                               Operation.get(bin2.name)
                              );
List<?> retList = (ArrayList<?>)record.getList(bin2.name);
System.out.println(retList.get(0));
System.out.println(retList.get(1));
System.out.println(retList.get(2));

client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(bin2));
record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);

client.operate(null,key,Operation.add(bin2));
record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);
```

Output:

```
test:2
2
4
6
(gen:2),(exp:394501613),(bins:(test:8))
(gen:3),(exp:394501613),(bins:(test:10))
```

Comment: Whatever value is there in that constructor, (Bin bToAdd = new Bin(name, value)) being passed to the add( .. bToAdd ..) operation, is what you will increment by.

Comment: Bin constructor is getting initialised in a different method. For eg. i have used this command                      
Bin incrementBin = new Bin("count", 1). RecordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.UPDATE , thus i believe PUT command is not required. Aerospike operate comand will upsert the record.

Comment: Yes. That should work. Let me edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: May be add: System.out.println(bin2);  inside your function, and see if the bin object is being passed correctly. I my code it prints:  test:2

Comment: Another way you can have unreliable behavior is if you are in AP mode, 3 node cluster, and your cluster is constantly falling apart and reforming back (split brain --> heal --> split brain --> heal) due to some networking issue between your 3 nodes.

Comment: I am performing multiple queries in a single transaction. ADD and GET in same transaction. Will it impact atomic increment operations ? because the concurrency level is very high in our application. Thus don't want to perform two separate transaction for ADD and GET.  command -> record = aerospikeClient.operate(aerospikeClient.writePolicyDefault, asKey, Operation.add(bin), Operation.get(bin.name)); . Records are not getting updated consistently in my case.

Comment: That should work atomically in the order of the operations.

Comment: Also added multi-ops example to the code example.